# How do i check if a user is logged in? Passport and discord oAuth2 (EJS)

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, discord, ejs

How do i check if the user is logged in EJS with passport and Discord oAuth2.

I want it to show 2 diffrent navbars and footers based on if the user is logged in or not so far i just get a pile of errors and a angry attitude.

I have gotten many errors based around the problem but not any errors i belive to be the cause of what i have tried wont work.

I have tried changing values in my database, just simply a if else statement in my EJS code. With negative results.

Here is the progress on what i have so far.

```
const { getPermissions } = require('../utils/utils');

// var isLoggedIn = false

function isAuthorized(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user) {
        console.log("User is logged in.");

        next(isLoggedIn = true);
    }
    else {
        console.log("User is not logged in.");
        
    }
}
router.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.render('home', {
        isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn()      
     }); 
    })




module.exports = router
```

Comment: You've not mentioned the very specific issue you're dealing with- is `req.user` undefined, etc.? I'd suggest you check (or even post here) your route on login and what you are doing there.

Answer (score 0):

I would base this on whether your UI has any tokens. A useful design pattern can be to proceed as follows:

- Define an interface to represent authentication related operations as in [this example of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- Most of your app can then be shielded from any OAuth specific details and can just ask the isLoggedIn question
- The implementation can then check whether tokens available, as in [this class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/web/webAuthenticator.ts)